# Shortcut that runs command prompt and runs two lines of code

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, shortcut

I open `cmd` and write `cd Desktop\PES` and then I write again `pes.exe` to run the `pes.exe` file. Now, I want to ask if the above two commands can be written as one in the cmd and how can I create a shortcut (right click -> New -> Shortcut) in order to run the above code?

Comment: The properties of a shortcut have the edit field __Start in__ which makes the usage of command `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PES"` useless as this is done by Windows before starting the application. Specify "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PES" for __Start in__ in shortcut properties and specify as command to execute the file `pes.exe` with full path, i.e. `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PES\pes.exe"`.

Comment: [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/) answers also your question. The ampersand makes it possible to run multiple commands from single line. The command line for the shortcut properties would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PES" & pes.exe`. But this solution is suboptimal, especially if `pes.exe` is a GUI application and therefore running a command process with a console window just for executing the GUI application is definitely not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a batch script? Write those commands into notepad and save with .bat extension. Can run as one command in cmd and, though wouldn't be technically a shortcut, could be saved to desktop.

Comment: But, you can create a shortcut to the .bat script on the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following command in your `shortcuts.xml` file. (In `<UserDefinedCommands></UserDefinedCommands>` section)

```
<Command name="Run in CMD" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="67">&quot;cmd.exe&quot; /K &quot;cd, c:\users&quot; & notepad</Command>
```

Essentially NPP is sending the following command. (`&` is used to enter multiple commands.)

```
cmd.exe /K "c:\users" & Notepad
```

The above command adds a shortcut in **Run** menu called '**Run in CMD**'.

1. The command opens the command prompt
2. Changes the directory to `c:\users`.
3. Open a Notepad.

**Note**:

- Do not change the `shortcuts.xml` in Notepad++, it may not save the changes. Rather use Notepad or other text editor to make those changes.
- You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to this command using `Shortcut Mapper`.